# Microsoft graph API doesn't save session token after successful login and token retrieval in Python Flask session

Tags: python, session, flask, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I have cloned a simple Microsoft graph login API from the official graph developers docs and changed the app config variables as per my registered app.
The authentication works successfully, but it's stuck at `graphCall` method where i redirect the user after a successful user authentication.
The console shows the token string, but it still redirects the user to my index page where the login button lays.

my full app file looks the following:

```
import uuid
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session  # https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session
import msal
import app_config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(app_config)
Session(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('index.html', user=session["user"], version=msal.__version__)

# @app.route("/getAToken")
# def getAToken():
#     if not session.get("user"):
#         return redirect(url_for("login"))
#     return render_template('getAToken.html')

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    session["state"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    # Technically we could use empty list [] as scopes to do just sign in,
    # here we choose to also collect end user consent upfront
    auth_url = _build_auth_url(scopes=app_config.SCOPE, state=session["state"])
    return render_template("login.html", auth_url=auth_url, version=msal.__version__)

@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)  # Its absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD
def authorized():
    if request.args.get('state') != session.get("state"):
        return redirect(url_for("index"))  # No-OP. Goes back to Index page
    if "error" in request.args:  # Authentication/Authorization failure
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=request.args)
    if request.args.get('code'):
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            request.args['code'],
            scopes=app_config.SCOPE,  # Misspelled scope would cause an HTTP 400 error here
            redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))
        if "error" in result:
            return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()  # Wipe out user and its token cache from session
    return redirect(  # Also logout from your tenant's web session
        app_config.AUTHORITY + "/oauth2/v2.0/logout" +
        "?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + url_for("index", _external=True))

@app.route("/graphcall")
def graphcall():
    token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config.SCOPE)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        app_config.ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},
        ).json()
    return render_template('display.html', result=graph_data)


def _load_cache():
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if session.get("token_cache"):
        cache.deserialize(session["token_cache"])
    return cache

def _save_cache(cache):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        session["token_cache"] = cache.serialize()

def _build_msal_app(cache=None, authority=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        app_config.CLIENT_ID, authority=authority or app_config.AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=app_config.CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)

def _build_auth_url(authority=None, scopes=None, state=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).get_authorization_request_url(
        scopes or [],
        state=state or str(uuid.uuid4()),
        redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))

def _get_token_from_cache(scope=None):
    cache = _load_cache()  # This web app maintains one cache per session
    cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = cca.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])
        _save_cache(cache)
        return result

app.jinja_env.globals.update(_build_auth_url=_build_auth_url)  # Used in template

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to redirect to /graphcall after your successful authentication, and it can be done my just modifying the code as shown below.

```
@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)
def authorized():
    if request.args.get('state') != session.get("state"):
        return redirect(url_for("graphcall")) 
    if "error" in request.args: 
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=request.args)
    if request.args.get('code'):
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            request.args['code'],
            scopes=app_config.SCOPE,
            redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))
        if "error" in result:
            return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
    return redirect(url_for("graphcall"))
```

You would be having an issue with the back button, you can change it to / in href so that it goes to index page. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was packages' versions conflict, I had to use a custom flask_session lib to get it to deal with the server session. My installed session lib had a problem saving the session variable after the request call, it always reset the session variable to 'none'.
Check https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/issues/35